# Configure WAMP to Allow iPad Testing of Subdomains via LAN

Tags: apache, ipad, wamp

I've currently got my WAMP environment configured so that the Windows 7 hosts file redirects wildcard sub-domains appropriately. What I would like to do is use my iPad which is connected to the same LAN as the development machine to test deployment without pushing the site live.

On the development machine I can view the site via `http://beta.localhost.com/` but the only way I can access the development machine from the iPad is via local IPv4 with the sub-domain as a folder for example `http://192.168.0.6/beta/` which breaks the design elements of the site due to how the site is designed to rewrite URLs and the nature of CSS relative pathing.

Is there a way to enable access to `http://beta.localhost.com/` directly from the iPad?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling around I figured it out. The trick was actually opening an additional port. I'm still open to any other solutions, but for the moment here's what I did to enable access:

1. Setup a Virtual Server on the LAN router to forward port 81 to the development machine's port 81 mapped through its local IPv4 address.
2. Opened port 81 on the Windows 7 development machine via Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules (via Left Pane) > New Rule (via Right Pane).

   ```
   Via Wizard:
   ~ Select Port
   ~ Select TCP, Specific Local Port (enter 81 into the box)
   ~ Select Allow Connection
   ~ Check Domain, Private and Public
   ~ Name and describe as you wish
   ```
3. Added the following code to the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:81
   <VirtualHost *:81>
       ServerName localhost.com
       ServerAlias www.localhost.com
       DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\beta"
       ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
       <directory "D:\wamp\www\beta">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
           Order Deny,Allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from all
       </directory>
   </VirtualHost></pre>
   ```

   *Take note of the inclusion of the "beta" sub-domain I included. Change this to whatever is relevant to your needs.
4. Add `Listen 81` to your Apache httpd.conf file.
5. Restart all services in WAMP. Access the "beta" (or whatever you decided on) via the public IP of your router using port 81, for example `255.255.255.255:81`.